# Increase pdf page width using wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

Increasing page width of the generated pdf seems very tricky.

I tried this while rendering my pdf:

```
:page_width => '3000'
```

but the above change had no effect at all!

But I tried this in my template instead:

```
<div style="width:3000px">
```

This increased my page width but also shrunk my font. Also, changing the 3000 to any higher number seems to make no difference at all!

Is there a cleaner way to increase page width? (I need approximately 3000 px wide)

Comment: This definitely increases the width but am not able to increase it any further

    :page_width => "20in"

Answer (score 0):

Try combine with the other options:

```
...
orientation: 'Landscape',
page_width: '3000',
dpi: '300
...
```

Not sure, but try pixels as unit of measurement too `page_width: '3000px'`?

Comment: Hi Sree - Thanks much for your suggestion; but I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work :(